# Translate this MySQL query to JPQL

Tags: mysql, jpql

I am not sure how would this MySQL query look in JPQL.
DETAILS:

```
select title
from post
order by (
  select count(postId)
  from comment
  where comment.postId=post.id
) desc;
```

EDIT:
Post table look:

```
mysql> desc post;
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| post_id       | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_content  | varchar(50000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_date     | datetime       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_summary  | varchar(1000)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post_title    | varchar(300)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_visitors | int(11)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| category_id   | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment table look:

```
mysql> desc comment;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment_content | varchar(600) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_date    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_title   | varchar(300) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is command in mysql, terminal.

```
mysql> select post_title from post order by (select count(post_id) from comment where comment.post_id=post.post_id) desc;
```

I tried this, but its not working:

```
SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY 
(SELECT c COUNT(c.getPost().getId()) 
from Comment c 
where c.getPost().getId()=p.getId()) 
desc
```

Comment: I am trying to get posts ordered by comments count. Most commented posts first.

Comment: I don't use JPQL, but from the documentation it looks much like ordinary SQL. I don't see method calls like `getPost()` in any of the examples at docs.oracle.com. Can't you access columns normally?

Comment: @Barmar Well, these tables are mapped with JPA to mysql database. So, getXXX() are getter methods in the corresponding classes. This is actually content in query parameter of the NamedQuery annotation.

Comment: From what I can tell, JPQL takes care of the mapping, you write the queries using normal `table.column` syntax. I suspect all you have to do is rewrite your query as a normal join, rather than using a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause. I'll show my suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used native `SQL` for getting result I need. So, its not really an answer to my question, but I will post what I did, and what works (with plain `SQL`).
Because, its not realized with `JPQL`, there isn't `named query` in an `entity class`, but `native query` has been used (inside the method of `DAO object`).

So, this is method content:

```
public List<Post> getMostCommentedPosts(){
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from post order by "
            + "(select count(post_id) from comment where comment.post_id=post.post_id) desc", Post.class);
    List<Post> resultList = (List<Post>) q.getResultList();

    if (resultList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else
        return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Main problem with non-working approach is calling methods of Java classes from JPQL query - that is not expected to work.

Assuming that significant properties of entities are roughly as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id int id;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "post") List<Comment> comments;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id int id;
    @ManyToOne Post post;
    //...
}
```

Then following should be enough with Hibernate+MySQL combo:

```
SELECT p 
FROM Post p 
ORDER BY SIZE(p.comments) DESC
```

JPA 2.0 specification requires bit more complex query, because what can be used in ORDER BY clause is rather limited:

> 1. A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to an orderable state field of an entity or embeddable class abstract schema type designated
>      in the SELECT clause by one of the follow- ing: • a
>      general_identification_variable • a
>      single_valued_object_path_expression
> 2. A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to the same state field of the same entity or embeddable abstract schema type as a
>      state_field_path_expression in the SELECT clause
> 3. A result_variable that refers to an orderable item in the SELECT clause for which the same result_variable has been specified. This may
>      be the result of an aggregate_expression, a scalar_expression, or a
>      state_field_path_expression in the SELECT clause.

Following query should work also with other implementations. It is of course little bit tedious that additional variable is part of the result then:

```
SELECT p, SIZE(p.comments) as ord  
FROM Post p 
ORDER BY ord DESC
```

Comment: Yes, this way result is not list of "clean" `Post` objects, what I actually need. Anyway, I haven't found a way to express this query in JPQL, so I have used native SQL. This is code excerpt creating query `Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from post order by (select count(post_id) from comment where comment.post_id=post.post_id) desc", Post.class);`

Comment: after more than a week, I am again facing this same issue. I realized that I can't use native query because it returns only properties for entity `Post`(`post` table columns). Even the result is ordered by number of posts comments, I can not see that number in the result. In the meanwhile I have learned that this kind of queries should be created using `JPA Criteria API`. Are you maybe familiar with `JPA Criteria API`? How should look common `JPA` criteria query for `SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY SIZE(p.comments) DESC`?

Comment: Not realizing (at the moment) that I have already been facing this issue, I have asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981160/jpa-mysql-whats-wrong-with-this-jpql-query .You can see entity classes code there, although it is similar code as you assumed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use JPQL, but maybe this will work (you can also use it in MySQL):

```
SELECT post_title, COUNT(c.post_id) AS c
FROM Post p
LEFT JOIN Comment c
ON p.post_id = c.post_id
ORDER BY c
```

Comment: Hmm, tried your plain SQL approach, doesn't work, getting exception: `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "COUNT ( *" at character 20 .....` (I am also new with JPQL)

Comment: Hmm, maybe it doesn't allow `COUNT(*)`, try the update

Comment: @Bramar Now, getting exception `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "LEFT JOIN Comment c" at character 54 ...`

Comment: Not sure why, I see `LEFT JOIN` in the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html

Comment: @Bramar cite from chapter on JPQL: _JPQL provides the ability to invoke native SQL queries._  So, i guess, native sql should work, don't know why its not working.