# JPA/MySQL - Whats wrong with this JPQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jpa, jpql

I have entity `Post`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getNewestPosts", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.date DESC"), // getting resultList ordered by date
    @NamedQuery(name = "getMostVisitedPosts", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.visitors DESC"), // ordered by most visited
    @NamedQuery(name = "getMostCommentedPosts", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY SIZE(p.comments) DESC")
})
public class Post implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "post_title", length=300, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "post_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "post_summary", length=1000, unique = false, nullable = true)
    private String summary;

    @Column(name = "post_content", length=50000, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "post_visitors", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer visitors;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { ALL }, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "post")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
...
```

Entity `Comment`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "comment_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "comment_title", length=300, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "comment_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "comment_content", length=600, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "post_id", referencedColumnName="post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;
...
```

Then, in the `PostDAOBean` is following method:

```
public List<Post> getMostCommentedPosts(int page, int postsPerPage){

    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("getMostCommentedPosts");
    q.setFirstResult(page - 1);
    q.setMaxResults(postsPerPage);
    List<Post> resultList = (List<Post>) q.getResultList();

    if (resultList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else
        return resultList;
}
```

When I call this method in servlet I get next exception:

```
[07.01.2014 09:06] Class name: class mbs2.blog.server.session.PostDAOBean, method name: public java.util.List mbs2.blog.server.session.PostDAOBean.getMostCommentedPosts(int,int) started
[07.01.2014 09:06] Class name: class mbs2.blog.server.session.PostDAOBean, method name: public java.util.List mbs2.blog.server.session.PostDAOBean.getMostCommentedPosts(int,int)<openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "SIZE" at character 31, but expected: ["AVG", "COUNT", "KEY", "MAX", "MIN", "SUM", "VALUE", <IDENTIFIER>]." while parsing JPQL "SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY SIZE(p.comments) DESC". See nested stack trace for original parse error.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:51)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:654)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1038)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createNamedQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:274)
    at mbs2.blog.server.session.PostDAOBean.getMostCommentedPosts(PostDAOBean.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

You can see that named query is: `SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY SIZE(p.comments) DESC`.

What is the cause of exception?

**EDIT**
OK, I see that function `SIZE(p.comments)` can not be used in JPQL to be ordered by it.

What is the alternative way of getting same data with JPQL? Proper JPQL query?

**EDIT**
Trying to implement this query with JPA Criteria API:

```
    public List<Post> getMostCommentedPosts(int page, int postsPerPage){

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Post> cq = cb.createQuery(Post.class);
        Root<Post> p = cq.from(Post.class);
        cq.select(p);
        cq.orderBy(cb.desc(???));
                ...???...
}
```

Need help with JPA Criteria API.

Comment: I didn't think you could put an aggregate in an `ORDER BY` in SQL.  Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @CodeChimp hm, other two named queries also use `ORDER BY` and their corresponding methods work

Comment: see the exception, man its saying that jpa supports ["AVG", "COUNT", "KEY", "MAX", "MIN", "SUM", "VALUE", <IDENTIFIER>]. and u r using SIZE function

Comment: Ah, I see the problem...there is no SIZE aggregate function.  It's in the error text.

Comment: @CodeChimp how should I modify then JPQL query to get all posts ordered by number of their comments? appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, compiler's barking: "Encountered "SIZE" at character 31, but expected: ["AVG", "COUNT", "KEY", "MAX", "MIN", "SUM", "VALUE", ]." while parsing JPQL...."

SIZE is a function that doesn't conform to the specification of the ORDER BY clause:

> The ORDER BY clause allows the objects or values that are returned by the query to be ordered. The syntax of the ORDER BY clause is
>   orderby_clause ::= ORDER BY orderby_item {, orderby_item}*
>   orderby_item ::= state_field_path_expression [ASC | DESC]
>   It is legal to specify DISTINCT with MAX or MIN, but it does not affect the result.
>   When the ORDER BY clause is used in a query, each element of the SELECT clause of the query must be one of the following: an identification variable x, optionally denoted as OBJECT(x), a single_valued_association_path_expression, or a state_field_path_expression.

Furthermore:

> The SIZE function returns an integer value, the number of elements of the collection. If the collection is empty, the SIZE function evaluates to zero.

---

Try this:

```
public List<Post> getMostCommentedPosts(int page, int postsPerPage){

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Post> cq = cb.createQuery(Post.class);
        Root<Post> p = cq.from(Post.class);
        cq.select(p).where(cb.isNotEmpty(p.get("comments")));
        List list = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        for(Set each : list)
        {
            System.out.println(each.size());
        }

}
```

Comment: yes, i see now, thanks. Can you help me: What can I use instead of `SIZE(p.comments)` to get number of comments in the set?

Comment: You can get the SIZE(p.comments), you just can't ORDER BY. SIZE() must be specified in a WHERE or HAVING clause. Something like SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE SIZE(p.comments) > 0. It doesn't look like there's an aggregate to work on the collection object itself, so you may have to do that on the Set itself. I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: Check out this page. Looks like you can use size with JPA CriteriaBuilder. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#Criteria_Query_Collection_Expressions_

Comment: Also see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html

Comment: JPA Criteria API looks so confusing. Are you familiar with it? See my answer edit, if you know how to finish that method?

Comment: I edited my answer with a code sample. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for helping, but this is not proper query. Query syntax is wrong - part `cb.isNotEmpty(p.get("comments"))`. I have asked another question on this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005794/building-jpa-criteria-api-query-sorting-by-number-of-elements-in-collection