# Building JPA Criteria API query - sorting by number of elements in collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I am having problem with building a query with JPA Criteria API.

Entities and significant properties:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id int id;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "post") Set<Comment> comments;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id int id;
    @ManyToOne Post post;
    //...
}
```

I need a query that will return all posts from db ordered by number of comments (`OneToMany` in `Post`).
At first I thought this can be implemented with `JPQL` like:

```
SELECT p 
FROM Post p 
ORDER BY SIZE(p.comments) DESC
```

But function `SIZE(...)` can not be used to be ordered by it in `JPQL`.

So, I found about `JPA Criteria API`, and tried following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Post> cq = cb.createQuery(Post.class);
Root<Post> p = cq.from(Post.class);
cq.select(p);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(p.get("comments")));
List<Post> resultList = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

With this query I am not getting proper results. I am aware that I am missing getting `size` of the set 'comments', but don't know how to add that part. I am not really familiar with `JPA Criteria API`. How should this query look to get all posts ordered by size of its `comments` field(set)?

Comment: Are you sure this won't work: `cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(p.<Collection>get("comments"))));` ?

Comment: Otherwise I think you'll have to use a `Subquery` and [CriteriaBuilder.count(Expression)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#count(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)).

Comment: @MartinAndersson yes,you are right, I was missing that `<Collection>` part, so `cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(p.<Collection<Comment>>get("comments"))));` is correct. You can post this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CriteriaBuilder.size(Expression)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#size-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-) returns an `Expression<Integer>` that you may use in the ORDER BY clause. This line of code:

```
p.get("comments")
```

..returns a `Path<X>` which extends `Expression<X>` so it is safe to use the returned value as an argument to Collection.size().

However, the previously quoted line of code is using a particular overloaded version of Path.get() which will make it impossible for the compiler to infer type parameter X. Instead, the type argument will be assumed to be `Object`. *But* Collection.size() has declared his Expression-parameter to be a "parameterized type" with an "upper bound" of `Collection` (*this is not reflected accurately in the first reference to CriteriaBuilder.size() in my answer, StackOverflow insist on erasing the type from the method signature. Please see the JavaDocs instead!*). So we must provide the type argument explicitly.

**Try this:**

```
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(p.<Collection>get("comments"))));
```

Comment: hey Martin, can you help me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137719/jpql-query-for-searching-if-a-word-string-is-consisted-in-one-of-entitys-fields

Comment: My I ask how to write orde by collection size in JPQL ?

Comment: How can I use this technique with JPA Criteria API?