# JPQL query for searching if a word/string is consisted in one of entity's fields

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

Basicaly, its similar like looking if certain word exists in sentence.
There is entity Post:

```
public class Post implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Column(name = "post_title", length=300, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "post_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;
        ...}
```

I am trying to implement `JPQL` query that will search for `Post` entity instances that have certain word/string ( `byTitle`, passed as an argument) in their `title` field, and two more arguments of `Date` type, that represents date range - `startDate` and `endDate`.

I have something like this on my mind:
`SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE :byTitle IN (set of strings created from parsing p.title field) AND p.date>=:startDate AND p.date<=endDate`

How to implement this kind of JPQL query? Or maybe JPA Criteria API should be used?

**EDIT:**
Like there is `someString.contains(someSubstring)` function in Java, is there anything similar in JPQL? Or Criteria API? And for comparing, it doesn't have to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have implemented it using JPQL `LIKE` paired with pattern expression:

```
SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE 
       p.title LIKE :pattern AND 
               p.date>=:startDate AND 
                     p.date<=:endDate
```

where `pattern = "%" + someString + "%"`.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that if the `pattern` contains user input, this might not be what one wants. Imagine a user typing `%` and being surprised at the results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use several LIKE clauses connected by OR:

```
WHERE (p.title LIKE :firstWord OR ... OR p.title LIKE :lastWord) AND p.date >= :startDate AND p.date <= :endDate
```

and then set parameters:

```
query.setParameter("firstWord", '%' + firstWord + '%');
...
query.setParameter("lastWord", '%' + lastWord + '%');
```

But the query may be slow. You can consider using a dedicated fulltext search tool like [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/).