# Order in JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, criteria-api

My entity looks like:

```
 class News {
    private Long id;
    private Author author;
    private List<Tag> tagsList;
    private String title;
    private List<Comment> commentsList;
    private Date modificationDate;
}
```

1) I would like to order result list by property size and date.

The part of my code:

```
cq.select(from).distinct(true)
                .orderBy(cb.desc(from.get("commentsList.size")), cb.desc(from.get("modificationDate")));
```

Of course the ".size" it wrong. How can I do it using criteria API?

2) How to add `Tags` from `tagsList` and `Author` in criteria?

Comment: size of a collection is done via CriteriaBuilder.size(...) with the argument being "from.get("commentsList")". Tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building JPA Criteria API query - sorting by number of elements in collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005794/building-jpa-criteria-api-query-sorting-by-number-of-elements-in-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the buildCriteria method solved my problems:

```
   CriteriaQuery<News> cq = cb.createQuery(News.class);
    Root<News> news = cq.from(News.class);
    cq = cq.select(news).distinct(true);

    if (sc != null) {
        boolean authorExist = sc.getAuthorId() != null;
        boolean tagsExist = sc.getTagIdsSet() != null && !sc.getTagIdsSet().isEmpty();

        if (authorExist && !tagsExist) {
            cq.where(cb.in(news.get("author").get("id")).value(sc.getAuthorId()));
        } else if (!authorExist && tagsExist) {
            cq.where(cb.or(addTags(cb, news, sc)));
        } else {
            cq.where(cb.and(
                    cb.in(news.get("author").get("id")).value(sc.getAuthorId()),
                    cb.or(addTags(cb, news, sc))
            ));
        }
    }

    return cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(news.<Collection>get("commentsList"))),
            cb.desc(news.get("modificationDate")));
```

Also `addTags` method:

```
 private static Predicate addTags(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<News> news, SearchCriteria sc) {
    In<Object> in = cb.in(news.get("tagsSet").get("id"));

    for (Long id : sc.getTagIdsSet()) {
        in = in.value(id);
    }

    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(from.<Collection>get("commentsList"))), cb.desc(from.get("modificationDate")));
```