# Order by in JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA Specifications for querying and I am unable to implement a use-case related to ordering. Please note that I am stuck with Specifications for some reason and cant switch to JPQL.

Here is the trimmed domain model:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Phone> phones; //contains both "active" & "inactive" phones
}


@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private boolean active;
  private String number;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Employee employee;
}
```

I need to pull all the employees and order them depending on the count of **active** phones they have. I have used the code -

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(cb.desc(cb.size(employee.get("phones"))));
cq.orderBy(orders);
```

When I run the code, the query that gets executed has

```
ORDER BY (SELECT 
        COUNT(phone4_.employee_id)
    FROM
        phone phone4_
    WHERE
        employee4_.id = phone4_.employee_id) DESC
```

I tried a lot of things but unable to add another condition to the WHERE logic which checks for **"active"** phones only. Please suggest.

**UPDATE :**

I did some research and tried the following to achieve the use case. However, I get the error - "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query"

```
Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Phone> phRoot= subquery.from(Phone.class);
Predicate p1 = cb.equal(root.get("id"), phRoot.get("employee").get("id"));
Predicate p2 = cb.isTrue(phRoot.get("active"));

cq.distinct(true);
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(cb.desc(subquery.select(cb.count(phRoot.get(ID))).where(p1, p2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make CriteriaBuilder sort on the size of a collection you need to specify that the property is a collection by adding `<Collection>`.

For you code this will be

```
orders.add(cb.desc(cb.size(employee.<Collection<Phone>>get("phones"))));
```

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027934/924036 for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: The code will sort the employees based on the number of phones(both active and inactive)...I need to sort the employees based on the number of active phones.

Comment: @Tapan Sorry for not catching that you wanted to sort on **active** phones.

Comment: no problem :)   I have been struggling with this use case for a week now..makes me wonder if JPA specifications even support this