# How to apply @Where clause on inner mappings

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've three tables with multi level relationship. I need to apply @Where clause on lower level class from top level mapping. Please find the below sample code below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class Table1{

// Here I need to add where clause to fetch table2 data based on table3 condition

/* 
 * SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
 *    table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t_id
 *    AND t3.id = 'some text';
 */

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "columnName", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Set<Table2> table2Data;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class Table2{

  @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Table3 table3Data;

  @Column(name = "column_name")
  String columnName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="table3")
public class Table3{
 
 @Column(name = "id")
 String id;

}
```

I'm using `table1.get("table2Data")` in one of my ORDER BY condition. This is pulling total table2 data. But I want only some specific data to be pulled from table2.

I tried adding @Where clause in table2 mapping like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class Table2{

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Where(clause = "table3Data.id = 'some text')
  Table3 data;
}
```

But it is not working from me as expected. Please correct me if I'm doing wrong and let me know your solutions or thoughts on this.

Comment: Why you can not just use jpql/hql for this?

Comment: Thanks for replying @SternK. We cannot use jpql/hql, we have to use jpa specifications only here.

Comment: This part of your mapping: `@ManyToOne(mappedBy = "id", ...)  Table3 table3Data;` looks incorrect. `mappedBy` should be used on the ToMany side of the association.

Comment: JPQL is part of the JPA specification

Comment: See chapter 4 of the specification: https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Entity
@Table(name=“table1”)
public class Table1{
// Here I need to add where clause to fetch table2 data based on table3 condition
/* 
 * SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
 *  table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t_id
 *  AND t3.id = ‘some text’;
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = “table1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy=table1)
Set<Table2> table2Data;
}
@Entity
@Table(name=“table2”)
public class Table2{
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = “table2_column_Id”)
private Table table1;
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = “table2”)
private List<Table3> table3=new ArrayList<>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name=“table3")
public class Table3{
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = “table3_column_Id”)
private Table2 table2;
```

Comment: George - Can you please have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834672/order-by-in-jpa-specification